# Call json file from url

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to call json file from url and get data. But no error and nothing working. I don't have any idea how to solve it.

**service**

```
export class JsonService {


  public getMenuData(): Observable<any> {
    
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      this.http.get('https://demored.ddns.net:50443/demored/path_image/menu.json').subscribe((response)=> {
        observer.next(response);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.getJson();
    
  }

  getJson(){
    this.jsonService.getMenuData().toPromise().then(data => {
      this.menuJson = data;
      console.log("Menu from json file ",this.menuJson);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error in fetching data',err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on Stackblitz?
Anyway, the website where you're trying to get the json has an expired certificate and presents a 404, I expect it to return an error, but it can be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the `GET` request on the service, where you convert the request into a promise with `toPromise()`. From there in any component you can call the method for the service declared in the **constructor** `this.serviceJson()` and resolve the promise with a `.then ()` or `.catch ()`

```
export class JsonService {
  
  getMenuData(): Promise<any> {
   return this.http.get<any>('https://demored.ddns.net:50443/demored/path_image/menu.json').toPromise()
  }
```

component

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.getJson();
    
  }

  async getJson(){
   await this.jsonService.getMenuData().then(data => {
      this.menuJson = data;
      console.log("Menu from json file ",this.menuJson);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error in fetching data',err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: Ok, make shore you use `async/await`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.., I got error `url` `A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword`